# Binomial Distribution (picking balls with return)

Tags: probability-distributions

In a box there are red, black and white balls (4 of each color). 
We pick one randomly out, and then return it back.
This is done 4 times.
Assume that X,Y,Z are the number of times that red, black and white balls were chosen, respectively.

A. What is the distribution of X,Y,Z? Is it Binomial?

B. What is the distribution of (X+Y) ? What is its variance? Can I consider it as "the number of failures of choosing white"?

C. What is the correlation between X and Y?

D. What is the correlation between (X+Y) and Z?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

A. Yes, the distributions of $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are binomial

B. Yes, you can consider it as "the number of failures of choosing white".

C. The first way is to calculate all the probabilities $\mathbb P(X=k,Y=m)$ for $k,m=0,1,2,3,4$. This is not so long since there at most $15$ nonzero probabilities and obvious symmetry $$\mathbb P(X=k,Y=m)=\mathbb P(X=m,Y=k)$$ takes place. And then find $$\mathbb E[XY]=\sum_{k=1}^4\sum_{m=1}^4km\mathbb P(X=k,Y=m).$$

The other way is symmetry argument $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Cov}(X,Z)=\text{Cov}(Y,Z)$ and variance properties 
$$
0=\text{Var}(X+Y+Z)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+\text{Var}(Z)+2\text{Cov}(X,Y)+2\text{Cov}(X,Z)+2\text{Cov}(Y,Z).
$$
Since $X+Y+Z=4$, its variance is zero.

D. Use linearity of covariance properties.